# Combine Sankeynetwork plot with a normal ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, d3.js, data-visualization

### Problem:

Is it possible to combine a `sankeyNetwork` plot and a normal `ggplot`?

I've tried using `ggarrange`, which returns the following error:

```
> ggarrange(p1, p2, rremove("x.text"), ncol = 1, nrow = 2)
$`1`

$`2`

attr(,"class")
[1] "list"      "ggarrange"
Warning messages:
1: In as_grob.default(plot) :
  Cannot convert object of class sankeyNetworkhtmlwidget into a grob.
2: In as_grob.default(plot) :
  Cannot convert object of class themegg into a grob.
```

and `cowplot`, which returns the following error:

```
> plot_grid(p1, p2, ncol = 1, align = 'v', axis = 'l', rel_widths = c(3,1))
Warning message:
In as_grob.default(plot) :
  Cannot convert object of class sankeyNetworkhtmlwidget into a grob.
```

It seems like in both instances the commands need to work with two grob files but are unable to convert the sankeyNetwork plot into this format.

Ideally i'd retain the interactive elements of the sankeyNetwork plot as I have about 10 categories in each column of my graph and with each flowing into the next this means 100 flows. As some of these are quite small, but still not insignificant, being able to hover over and highlight them is key for being able to see the patterns between nodes.

Ultimately I also want the bar chart to be only approximately 1/3 the height of the Sankey plot, and stacked on top.

### For a reproducible example:

You can use this code to make a Sankey plot ([source](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/323-sankey-diagram-with-the-networkd3-library.html)):

```
# Load package
library(networkD3)
 
# Load energy projection data
URL <- "https://cdn.rawgit.com/christophergandrud/networkD3/master/JSONdata/energy.json"
Energy <- jsonlite::fromJSON(URL)

 
# Now we have 2 data frames: a 'links' data frame with 3 columns (from, to, value), and a 'nodes' data frame that gives the name of each node.
head( Energy$links )
head( Energy$nodes )
 
# Thus we can plot it
p1 <- sankeyNetwork(Links = Energy$links, Nodes = Energy$nodes, Source = "source",
              Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
              units = "TWh", fontSize = 12, nodeWidth = 30)
p1
```

which produces an interactive version of:
[image]

And this code to make a regular ggplot plot:

```
p2 <- ggplot(mpg, aes(class)) + geom_bar()
p2
```

which produces:

[image]

Comment: “Combine” into what? They are fundamentally different things. One typically creates a static raster or vector image, like a PNG. The other creates a mini HTML webpage with an interactive JavaScript widget. What is your desired outcome?

Comment: Thanks for your question. I'm modeling a journey through an ecosystem and at any given stage x% of ppl exit the ecosystem. I previously had 'exit' as a node in all but the 1st column of the sankey, but by the time you get to the 3rd column it takes up such a large % of the column the other nodes are hard to view. So I removed 'exit' from each column and normalized remaining values to a %. But I still want to show 'exit', so my idea was to have a bar graph running along the top (and where the bars line up with the columns) of the sankey to show the % of ppl remaining in the ecosystem

Comment: I was asking about the final output format. Do you want an image file? An HTML page? A web accessible interactive widget?

Comment: Ah I see. I'm still thinking that through. At first I was thinking a Shiny app but i've just learned that doesn't conform to my company's privacy policies, so will probably want to find a way to integrate it into a Tableau dashboard and have a drop-down menu to change the flows based on user characteristics (e.g. gender, age group)